# Smalltalk collections

Tags: sorting, collections, smalltalk

If I have an array of employees, how can I sorted based on employee last name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
employees sortBy: [:a :b | a lastName > b lastName]
```

Answer (score 6):

If we make these assumptions:

1. The Array instance is held in a variable named *employees*
2. The Array holds a collection of instances that all respond to the message *lastName* by returning a String instance
3. You want to sort the collection in ascending order

Then you can get the job done with the following code fragment:

```
 employees asSortedCollection: [ :a :b | a lastName < b lastName ]
```

This code sends the *asSortedCollection:* keyword message to the Array instance named *employees*. It passes in the Block instance, delimited by the square brackets, as the parameter to that keyword message. The Block passed in has two arguments that are named *a* and *b* and are marked by the preceding colon character all before the | character. The code within the Block after the | character will then be used to sort all the elements from the *employees* Array and add them to a new instance of the class SortedCollection.

Note, though, that this code ends up returning a new collection that holds the same items also held by *employees*, but now in the desired order. In fact, that new collection holds onto the sort criteria (the Block instance that was used as the parameter to the *asSortedCollection:* message) and as you add more instances to that collection in the future they will automatically be inserted in the correct sort order.